# Custom folder icons for Dropbox, Google Drive, and Github in the Ubuntu 15.04 design?

Tags: 15.04, icons, dropbox

For design consistencies, I would like to set custom folder icons for my custom folders of the services Dropbox, Google Drive, and Github. Currently, my home folder looks as follows:

[image]

Are there custom folder icons for these three services that are specifically made to tailor the design of Ubuntu 15.04?